# Angular 2+ Returning value from function in service to function call in other service

Tags: angular, typescript

I call a function in an other service:

```
this.response = this.groupingService.handleGroupingIntent(...);
```

In the function itself in the other service I call another function in another service:

```
handleGroupingIntent(){
this.tablePlanService.group(...).then(() => {return true;}).catch(() => {return false;})
}
```

and this function looks like this in the third service:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const onSuccess = () => resolve();
      const onError = (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        const errorHandler = this.httpErrorResponseHandler(
          `Serverfehler beim Gruppieren von Tisch ${tableToAdd.number}` +
          ` zu Tisch ${masterTable.number}.`);
        errorHandler(err);
        reject();
      };

      this.http.post(`/api/table-plan/groupings`, data)
        .subscribe(onSuccess, onError);
    });
  }
```

I want to set the `this.response` variable to true or false by the then/catch clause in the second function but it returns `undefined`.

How should I solve this issue?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to return a `Promise` from `handleGroupingIntent()` function as well.

Comment: You don't need `new Promise` here; even if you don't want to use observables, you can use `toPromise` rather than wrapping them like that. Also note that you're not handling the stream's values correctly at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You Should return a `Promise` from `handleGroupingIntent()` as well.**

**Try this.**

```
handleGroupingIntent(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.tablePlanService.group(...)
            .then(() => {

                resolve(true)
            }).catch(() => {

            reject(false)
        })
    });
}
```

**Call `handleGroupingIntent()` function like below.**

```
this.groupingService.handleGroupingIntent(...)
    .then((data) => {

        this.response = data;
    }).catch((data) => {

        this.response = data;
});
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: Why create a whole `new Promise` instead of just adding `return`?

Comment: If you have a better way than this please post it as an answer. then I also can learn new things.

Comment: I simply returned the `this.tablePlanService.group(...)` like @jonrsharpe mentioned, removed `then() catch()`and called `handleGroupingIntent()` like @SudarshanaDayananda mentioned.

Comment: @Anton Hoerl The issue in your question was with `handleGroupingIntent()` function. It should be an asynchronous function. but you were calling it as a normal function thats way the response was undefined. I gave the answer only for your issue. not consider about other process